# getting data from controls in <asp:wizard>

Tags: asp.net, wizard

Hi
Is there a way to get data on the "last step" from previous steps?
I am interested in pulling data from couple of controls in each step, and then build the object and insert the new object to the data base.
Thanks for every one who helps me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can still reference controls in earlier steps, regardless of what step the wizard is currently on.

What did you try and what was the result?

Comment: woo that was fast! I have built a wizard step named: LogoWizardStep, inside I have added a user control. I try to get the text from a textbox within this user control

Comment: How hard do I need to work to get critical information from you? What did you try and what was the result?

Comment: I have tried to get to the LogoStepWizard and then to extract something from the properties, but I can't find the properties of the user control.

Comment: thanks anyway, sorry my question was confusing. I needed to set public Properties  for the user control.

Comment: Please understand that I cannot see your project and do not know what you've tried or what was the result. The only way people can help is if you provide this information. As far as I'm concerned, there is no problem accessing controls displayed in other steps of a Wizard on the same page. Based on the information I have, that's my answer. Anyway, if I understand correctly, you've resolved the problem. That's great.